# How to remove this shower head arm

Tags: plumbing, shower, adhesive

Trying to replace the tub and shower fixtures when I encountered this light brown, <s>cement like</s> hard but gummy advesive liberally applied all over the joint.

How do I remove this?

[image: shower arm with adhesive]

Answer (score 2):

Simply unscrew it. The sealant/adhesive will break away from the wall as you unscrew it and stay attached to the pipe.

Comment: Thanks Jeff...simply unscrewing it didn't work. (First thing I tried, and also why I posted.) Ultimately I took a wood chisel to it, then after I had some gouges in it, I used needle nose pliers to remove small bits until I could grip and remove larger chunks. Toward the back of the cavity, the adhesive, or whatever it was, was less adhesed to the surfaces and came out a lot easier. Once this crap was gone, I was finally able to rotate the arm. I'll refrain from posting my own answer in hopes that someone might identify the brown stuff and offer a less hostile approach than I used. :)